# Seperating h tags & p tags centrally

Tags: html, css

I want to centrally align h tags and p tags but I can't seem to separate the sections nicely. [Here is the preview of what happens](https://gyazo.com/31321df95ff30e0570478ee8d93bad18)

What I would like is to have space between the three "boxes" of information and make everything central. I tried to add padding in between the `.top-row` class but it seems to always stick together.

HTML:

```
<section>
      <div class="container">
        <h1>TOPICS COVERED</h1>
        <p id=intro-p>There are six essential parts to building a CPU, let's
        go through them briefly</p>
      <div class="top-row">
        <div class="box1">
        <h3>BINAY & LOGIC</h3>
        <p>Before all, one needs to be comfortable with lab material & binary logic</p>
     </div>
     <div class="box2">
        <h3>Timing Signal Generator</h3>
        <p>The timing signal generator for the computer is a clock with a cycle that
        repeats. It allows the computer the amount of time needed to permorm operations.</p>
      </div>
      <div class="box3">
        <h3>Bus, Arithmetic Unit & Program Counter</h3>
        <p>In order to efficiently spread data throughout the breadboard, the data can be spread in a bus.
        he program counter of a computer holds the location of an execution to be executed.</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="bottom-row">

    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

CSS:

```
#topics{
 padding: 25px;
 background-color: #f5f6fa;
}

#topics h1{
 font-size: 30px;
 font-weight: 400px;
 letter-spacing: 2.5px;
 text-align: center;
 color: #282828;
}

#intro-p {
 text-align: center;
 color: #282828;
 font-size: 20px;
 letter-spacing: 2.5px;
}

.top-row{
 display: flex;
}

 .top-row h3{
 padding-left: 0px;
 text-transform: uppercase;
 }

.top-row p{
 text-align: justify;
 color: #282828;
 font-size: 14px;
 letter-spacing: 0.5px;
 }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The top row will only pad the container as a whole. What you want to do is pad the top row's children. You can do that by selecting them and adding padding. Further, since you are using flexbox, you can add flex to them to choose how they shrink, grow and their base size. Something like this would work for you. The text-align center will only center the heading as the paragraph tags have justify on them. If you want them centered, then remove that. Also, the flex-basis, third number on flex, could also be set to auto or unset if you don't want them to be equal. Find more on flexbox here: https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

```
.top-row > div {
    padding: 20px;
    text-align: center;
    flex: 1 1 33%;
}
```

Comment: Hey @moe, if this helped, please don't forget to mark as the answer.